# Mapping custom sidebar template to any document named "index.rst"

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Suppose I have the following project structure:

```
/
    index.rst
    1/
        index.rst
        a.rst
    2/
        index.rst
        b.rst
        3/
            index.rst
            c.rst
```

How can I create an [html_sidebars](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-html_sidebars) rule in Sphinx's `conf.py` which applies to all files named `index.rst`? If possible, please provide supporting Sphinx documentation explaining the various wildcard characters that can be used with `html_sidebars`.

Or do I have to explicitly specify every file...

```
html_sidebars = {'**': ['non-index-template.html'],
                 'index.rst': ['index-template.html'],
                 '1/index.rst': ['index-template.html'],
                 '2/index.rst': ['index-template.html'],
                 '3/index.rst': ['index-template.html']
}
```

Tangential question, is there a way to reference the value of a dictionary key within that dictionary? E.g.

```
html_sidebars = {'**': ['non-index-template.html'],
                 'index.rst': ['index-template.html'],
                 '1/index.rst': [this['index.rst']],
                 '2/index.rst': [this['index.rst']],
                 '3/index.rst': [this['index.rst']]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a footnote in [The build configuration file](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#id3):

> A note on available globbing syntax: you can use the standard shell
>   constructs *, ?, [...] and [!...] with the feature that these
>   all don’t match slashes. A double star ** can be used to match any
>   sequence of characters including slashes.

Therefore, the following will accomplish what I'm after (let me know if there's a cleaner way with the available syntax):

```
html_sidebars = {'**[!i][!n][!d][!e][!x]': ['non-index-sidebar.html'],
                 '**index': ['index-sidebar.html'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this question in the [sphinx-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/Ed2ljxMH22s) Google Group. Here is an answer from [Takayuki Shimizukawa](http://about.me/shimizukawa).

This might work, but note that it emits warnings:

```
html_sidebars = { 
    '**': ['non-index-template.html'], 
    '**/index': ['index-template.html'], 
    'index': ['index-template.html']
}
```

Re: referencing the value of a dictionary key within that dictionary:

```
html_sidebars = { 
    '**': ['non-index-template.html'], 
    'index.rst': ['index-template.html']
} 
html_sidebars['1/index.rst'] = html_sidebars['index.rst'] 
html_sidebars['2/index.rst'] = html_sidebars['index.rst'] 
html_sidebars['3/index.rst'] = html_sidebars['index.rst']
```

Or,

```
index_sidebars = ['index-template.html'] 
html_sidebars = { 
    '**': ['non-index-template.html'], 
    'index.rst': index_sidebars, 
    '1/index.rst': index_sidebars, 
    '2/index.rst': index_sidebars, 
    '3/index.rst': index_sidebars
}
```